# Kivy: How to get the id of an object from itself?

Tags: python, kivy, ids

I use a lot `ids` in kivy. I would like to get the `id` of my object from itself but I don't know how to write it correctly.  (`self.id` doesn't work, it return `None`)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    ObjBoxLayout:
        id: my_box
'''

class MyApp(App):
   def build(self):
       box = Builder.load_string(KV)
       print(box.ids.keys())
       return box


class ObjBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print(self.id)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this, although technically you could iterate through the root's ids to find the one that matches.

If you want this kind of functionality, it's probably a good idea to add your own identifying property that you set and access.

Comment: I'm gonna do it in a custom way, thanks for the answer. :)